# Keep query strings when navigating between child routers

Tags: javascript, durandal

Here's my child router and the view code:

```
router.createChildRouter().makeRelative({
  moduleId: 'products',
  fromParent: true,
  dynamicHash: ':id'
}).map([
  { route: 'specs', title: 'Specs', moduleId: 'specs', nav: true },
  { route: 'reviews', title: 'Reviews', moduleId: 'reviews', nav: true }
]).buildNavigationModel();

<ul class="tabs" data-bind="foreach: router.navigationModel()">
   <li data-bind="css: { selected: isActive }"><a href="{{dynamicHash}}">{{title}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

which will produce two tabs with the following URLs:

- `example.com/#products/200/specs`
- `example.com/#products/200/reviews`

I have a toolbar on my reviews page that sorts the content by date or by rating, so the URL becomes:

- `example.com/#products/200/reviews?date=asc&rating=desc`

But when I switch tabs and come back, I lose the query strings. Is there way to keep them in the URL until I clear the filters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing your exact implementation is there any reason to not just set this inside of a modules whose responsibility is to manage state?

products/(id)/specs view model / w/e -

```
define (['config.queryparams'], function (queryParams) {

    var ctor = function () {
        var self = this;
        // Assume the queryParms module has an observable called parameters
        self.queryparameters = queryParams.parameters;
    }

    ctor.prototype.active(id, querystring) {
        var self = this;
        // Set the queryParams.parameters observable to the query string
        self.queryparameters(querystring);
    }

    return ctor;

});
```

Then in your config.queryparams module -

```
define([], function () {

    var parameters = ko.observable();

    var module = {
        parameters: parameters
    }

});
```

Now just reference config.queryparams from your other module and it is shared.  Make sense?